# Nginx Passing to Servers Based on URI

Tags: nginx, location, uri, reverse-proxy

I have been setting up Nginx on my router, and creating subdomains (with CNAMES) to access various components within my network.  It has mostly been fairly easy, until I have come to the cameras which are proving to be a problem.

They are basic IP cameras and to date I had opened each one on a different port.  They have basic authentication, and once that has been entered I am presented with a live view.

Like all the other components I have set up so far (and they all work) I started by configuring one:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name cam.example.co.uk;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.101:2001;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Hitting `cam.example.co.uk` from either LAN or WAN gives me a username and password prompt and then the live view loads.

Since there are 9 cameras, I thought it would be a good idea to use `/1`, `/2`, `/3` etc. at the end to direct me to each one rather can creating subdomains.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name cam.example.co.uk;

    location /1/ {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.101:2001;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

     location /2/ {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.102:2002;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

With that I got 404 not found errors, and messages in the logs such as:

```
"/usr/html/new/index.htm" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

Some Googling later I found out that I may need to specify the URI as well in the proxy_pass line, so I changed them to look like:

```
proxy_pass http://192.168.1.102:2002/new/index.htm;
```

This then results in the username and password prompt, but when the credentials are entered, all I am left with is a blank screen.  It worked fine when it was just `location /` so no idea why nothing is showing now.

I have a feeling that it is putting the URI in somewhere, but I have no idea where/why or what to do about it.

---

**EDIT**

Been Googling and trying  various things:

```
location /1 {
    resolver 127.0.0.1;
    set $backend "http://192.168.1.101:2001/new/index.htm";
    proxy_pass $backend;
    proxy_buffering  on;
    proxy_redirect http://192.168.1.101:2001/new/index.htm http://cam.example.co.uk/1;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Then going to this in the browser `cams.example.co.uk/1` brings up the username and password prompt, but then displays a blank page.  Looking at the Chrome developer tools I can see unexpected token errors, and it looks like it isn't loading the .js files properly.

Answer (score 0):

If the proxy_pass directive is specified with a URI, then when a request is passed to the server, the part of a normalized request URI matching the location is replaced by a URI specified in the directive.

Try this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name cam.example.co.uk;

    location /1/ {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.101:2001/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_redirect http://192.168.1.101:2001/ http://cam.example.co.uk/1/;
    }

     location /2/ {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.102:2002/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_redirect http://192.168.1.101:2002/ http://cam.example.co.uk/2/;
    }
}
```

Source: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass

Comment: Since I posted my question, putting the / at the end of the proxy_pass is something I have already tried.  Made absolutely no difference :(

Comment: Applied the changed and restarted Nginx... still get this: ""/usr/html/new/index.htm" failed (2: No such file or directory)".  Could Nginx somehow be remembering previous paths and doing something funny?

Comment: Nope, not even sure what the /usr/html/ is all about.   I have been tinkering since you first posted, and am just about to update the original question.